# Setting gasLimit hides actual error returned from contract

Tags: gas, dapps, ethers.js, gas-limit

I have a minting smart contract deployed on Rinkeby and using dapp to call mint function using `ethers.js`. However I’m kind of stuck in loop of two problems that revolve around each other.

1- *If I don’t set an explicit `gasLimit` prop while calling the contract function then 60% of calls just fail with error `execution reverted`* even before reaching smart contract

2- *If I do set an explicit `gasLimit` prop while calling the contract function then the error messages returned from contract `require` statement are suppressed and instead I get an error message like below:*

**The call to function:**

```
const res = await contract.mint(this.price, { gasPrice: gas, gasLimit: 5000000 });

await res.wait();
```

**The error:**

> Error: transaction failed (transactionHash=“0xa2e46885914f2b1870486f7131efcf9c4d4b7d81ed1561c28e6a1bfac95c53a9”, transaction={“hash”:“0xa2e46885914f2b1870486f7131efcf9c4d4b7d81ed1561c28e6a1bfac95c53a9”,“type”:2,“accessList”:null,“blockHash”:null,“blockNumber”:null,“transactionIndex”:null,“confirmations”:0,“from”:“0xF58426982f839DAC71904724ab14BcF5972Eba2E”,“gasPrice”:{“type”:“BigNumber”,“hex”:“0x77359410"},“maxPriorityFeePerGas”:{“type”:“BigNumber”,“hex”:“0x77359410”},“maxFeePerGas”:{“type”:“BigNumber”,“hex”:“0x77359410"},“gasLimit”:{“type”:“BigNumber”,“hex”:“0x895440”},“to”:“0x26fD3fB4dA905308f6c78611BbB02CDc73841EdD”,“value”:{“type”:“BigNumber”,“hex”:“0x00"},“nonce”:3,“data”:“0x253a85a10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000”,“r”:“0x76b49bdb7717926002763415df6def5bea0608e9e37bd4e8c15e6ddd658f9dca”,“s”:“0x2286de763ccc12074a7a83cd7f0717ed6a5e369d5213e70612a9d16570f9a708”,“v”:1,“creates”:null,“chainId”:0}, receipt={“to”:“0x26fD3fB4dA905308f6c78611BbB02CDc73841EdD”,“from”:“0xF58426982f839DAC71904724ab14BcF5972Eba2E”,“contractAddress”:null,“transactionIndex”:7,“gasUsed”:{“type”:“BigNumber”,“hex”:“0x775e”},“logsBloom”:“0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000”,“blockHash”:“0x90b9e011ddea79a9962ce7149d79c2159082af5fbf69fe305dcb542b1cef97b9”,“transactionHash”:“0xa2e46885914f2b1870486f7131efcf9c4d4b7d81ed1561c28e6a1bfac95c53a9”,“logs”:[],“blockNumber”:10123633,“confirmations”:2,“cumulativeGasUsed”:{“type”:“BigNumber”,“hex”:“0x038cfc”},“effectiveGasPrice”:{“type”:“BigNumber”,“hex”:“0x77359410"},“status”:0,“type”:2,“byzantium”:true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.5.2)

Is there anyway I can set `gasLimit` and still get actual error string returned from smart contract? Also, an explanation to this behaviour would help. TIA!